# Make TCL hash non case sensitive

Tags: hash, tcl

Is there a chance to have the hash keys in a TCL array non case sensitive?

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
% set hash(aBc) Winner
Winner
% puts $hash(abc)
can't read "hash(abc)": no such element in array
%
```

Yes, I can use tolower

```
% set hash([string tolower dEf]) Loser
Loser
% puts $hash(def)
Loser
%
```

Just wondering if there is a faint chance for a solution that works globally on my hash?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation of arrays has no way to express what you've asked for; you have to `string tolower` (or otherwise make consistent; for example, `string toupper` would also work) the keys before use. I could conceive of this changing in the future via some sort of `array` subcommand… but that is pure speculation.

Dictionaries are much less likely to ever get such a capability, as they're pure values and not named entities.